# How can I center UI elements in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a login screen, but when I center the elements for one device, it doesn't center them for all devices. How can I center them for all devices in Xcode 8?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will actually be centered at runtime. You just need to update the view's frame in Interface Builder.

Just select the view that's off and click the update button in the lower right corner:

[image: Update Frame(s)]

If you want Interface Builder to automatically update your frames make sure the **Automatically Refresh View** option is enabled in Xcode's *Editor* menu:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the view menu in the top menu bar? I don't see Automatically Refresh View there.

Comment: You're right. It's the _Editor_ menu. Updated my answer accordingly.